# Get size of text in an SVG without access to the DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg

I'd like to create an array of instructions ON THE SERVER for how to create an SVG element, then pass that data to the browser to render in a simple loop. That's mostly straightforward, except that my calculations depend on the amount of space some text takes and I don't know how to get that except by drawing it and using `getBBox()`, but that requires a DOM.

This problem also comes up on the client when I want to do the calculations for the SVG before it is visible.

Is there a way to do this? In thinking about it, it sounds complicated for node.js to do, especially since it can be affected by CSS, but if we assume that the font size, etc, is specified on the element itself, is there a way?

Note that the contents of the SVG is completely dynamic and the font size, etc, can be specified by the user on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it is not possible to do that.
Especially on the server side.
Text rendering heavely depends not only on the font face, size, line heights and other typography stuff, but also on the browser and even OS it is rendered on.

To get the precise result, I'd recomment to render text in the browser and get it's bounding box.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I was just hoping someone had a bright idea.

Comment: What I ended up doing is creating a separate SVG on the page that I know is present and not hidden and using that just for calculations.